# Efficiently working with bootstrap

Tags: ruby, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5, frontend

What is the most efficient way of working with bootstrap in a rails application. Working in this context means changing bootstrap variables and loading just what is required.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?, just need to understand how to work with bootstrap effectively in rails.

Answer (score 1):

You propably want to use the `bootstrap` gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap

How to change variables is in the documentation of the github page: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem